# Python for RSA signature

Tags: python, rsa

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5 as pk 
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA 

privatekey=RSA.importKey(open('pkcs8_rsa_private_key.pem','r').read())
def sign(self,signdata): 
    h=SHA.new(signdata) 
    signer = pk.new(privatekey) 
    signn=signer.sign(h) 
    signn=base64.b64encode(signn) 
    return signn
```

Just like this, but my `privatekey` is a string not a file. How I do it?
And how can I make `privatekey` string to pkcs8 format?

Comment: You can use StringIO read a string as a file, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html. According to https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5.PKCS115_Cipher-class.html, private key must be an RSA key object and according to https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA-module.html such can be created with RSA.  
generate(bits, randfunc=None, progress_func=None, e=65537)

Comment: I had a private key, it is string of value from a private_key.pem file. I don't konw how to use this for sign. I need make it is pkcs8 format,how can i do ?